# Concurrency issue in Java swing

Tags: java, swing, swingworker

I'm using a SwingWorker to refresh a JList which is full of files in the current directory. To prevent the user from running the refresh command multiple times, I'm locking the command with a AtomicBoolean while it runs but I am still sometimes getting a strange issue with a NullPointerException when using the put() of the HashTable and sometimes it's a IllegalStateException with the Matcher(). Is the AtomicBoolean not sufficient enough to prevent concurrency issues?

The line in question is `syntaxHash.put(file.getAbsolutePath(), m.group(1));` in the `doInBackground()` function

```
public boolean fillWithFiles(final String EXEC_DIR) {
    if (started.compareAndSet(false, true)) {   //Lock the function
        FillWithFilesWorker worker = new FillWithFilesWorker();
        worker.execute();   //Run the worker
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;   //There is a thread in the function still
    }
}

private class FillWithFilesWorker extends SwingWorker<Void, Boolean> {

    @Override
    public Void doInBackground() {
        try {
            publish(true);  //disable JList and activate wait cursor
            if (syntaxHash != null) syntaxHash.clear();

            File currentFolder = new File(HelperWindow.EXEC_DIR);
            File[] currentRexScripts = currentFolder.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
                public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
                    return name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".txt");
                }
            });

            listModel = new DefaultListModel<String>();
            for (File file : currentRexScripts) {
                listModel.addElement(file.getAbsolutePath());
            }

            final File[] tempCurrentRexScripts = currentRexScripts;
            for (File file : tempCurrentRexScripts) {
                try {
                    try (Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(file)) {
                        while (fileScanner.hasNext()) {
                            String s = fileScanner.nextLine();
                            m = syntax.matcher(s);
                            if (m.find()) {
                                syntaxHash.put(file.getAbsolutePath(), m.group(1));
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void done() {
        JListHelper.this.setModel(listModel);
        HelperWindow.scrollPane.setCursor(Cursor.getDefaultCursor());
        JListHelper.this.setEnabled(true);
        started.set(false);
    }

    @Override
    protected void process(List<Boolean> chunks) {
        for (Boolean chunk : chunks) {
            if (chunk) {
                HelperWindow.scrollPane.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.WAIT_CURSOR));
                JListHelper.this.setEnabled(false);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the `if (syntaxHash != null) syntaxHash.clear()` line strongly implies that at least *sometimes* `syntaxHash` may be `null`.  Under what circumstances is this true?  Could `syntaxHash` be made into a variable local to this method?

Comment: Similar question with `Matcher m`.  Where is that declared?  Why is it not local to the thread class or better yet, the loop?

Comment: They are declared as private when the object is instantiated. `syntaxHash` can never be null so there should never be checked if null. The `Matcher m` object is also declared when the object is instantiated as private but can be null in this piece of code. However, it should never be null at the line where it is thrown because it is set equal to a Matcher object.

Comment: private doesn't mean much in the face of concurrency.  Are they private members of the class that this one is nested in?  The behavior you're seeing would seem to indicate that they're being used by more than one thread (you're right about that), but that can't happen with a variable local to the method.

Comment: Yes they're private members of the class. So there must be multiple threads accessing the objects but how is that possible with the atomic boolean lock blocking the function?

Comment: Because the atomic boolean only protects this function.  That's why these should be local.  If they're accessed *outside* the function, you'll get contention issues.

Comment: Moving the `Matcher` object to be local to the function fixed the problem. Thanks! I put the `syntaxHash` in a synchronized block since it can't be made local due to the design.